# Voice Memo file location, Ventura 13.5.2

Tags: macos, icloud, filesystem, voice-memo

Up until two days ago, my voice memos happily lived in `~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.voicememos/Recordings`. Every time I'd record something, an m4a file would pop into that library, which I could then process using other tools. This was great.

Suddenly, this stopped working. The voice memos still show up in the app: They're all right there. But that path is now empty.

I tried right-clicking an entry in Voice Memos and choosing Show in Finder, but that only yields a temporary directory, not where the recordings "actually" live.

Any idea? Is this a recent macOS update thing? what's weird is that they definitely show up in the app, but not in the folder on my filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

You could try right-/control-clicking a recording in Voice Memos and selecting Services > Show in Finder:

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, this takes me to a temp folder. Do you use Ventura? Does Voice Memos stll put your files in the folder shown in my question? In other words, is it a "just me" issue?

Comment: Yes, I have tested this on Ventura. It's not a "just me" issue. Voice Memos doesn't seem to put voice recordings in `~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.voicememos/Recordings` anymore - at least, not when synced from an iphone. My folder is something like `/private/var/folders/7w/{30-char folder}/T/com.apple.VoiceMemos/.com.apple.uikit.itemprovider.temporary.YlZCOs/`. Not sure if this is a temporary placement from iCloud or not, let alone, I don't know where the original voice memos live.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble... not sure how I found them, but here's the path:

**Finder > Go > Go to Folder**:
`Users/<user_name>/Library/Containers/com.apple.VoiceMemos/Data/Library/Application Support/Recordings`

Running Ventura 13.6.1 on 2018 MacBook Pro - remember to add folder location to your Favorites!